# How to identify and verifying tokenId from google API?

Tags: java, android

I can't find any solution for as i think very general issue...

I use `google API` for `LogIn`, and according to [this article](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start) i can get `tokenId` using this method

```
private String getTokenId(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    String tokenId = null;
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
    if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        tokenId = googleSignInAccount.getIdToken();
    }
    return tokenId;
}
```

it is standard method, but why this method retern back token id which the contains 857 char of String? And i can't verify it with standard link

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token= <857 char>;
```

and i get back this response

```
{
"error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

I am sure if google provide method to get `token id` there is have to be a method to verify it...

What am i doing wrong?